# AutoPy - Point out of bounds (smooth_move)

Tags: python, autopy

Hi so i'm trying to move my cursor on screen using the `smooth_move` function from the `AutoPy` module.

My screen resolution is `1920x1080`

But when i execute this code, `autopy.mouse.smooth_move(1700, 0)`

I get the following Error

```
ValueError: Point out of bounds
```

I did a little testing and found out that if i set `1250` as the `x` variable in the `smooth_move` function, it moves the cursor towards the end of my screen.

Hurh??? Shouldn't the `x` variable be `1920` since that's my monitors resolution????

Comment: Did you check the result of `autopy.screen.size()`? There might be a difference between the points and the pixels on the screen due to scaling. Disclaimer: I never worked with `autopy`, so this is a guess based on the information in the documentation.

Comment: @Denise,  how much u set for cam w * h?

Answer (score 0):

Use autopy.screen.scale()

```
scale = autopy.screen.scale()
autopy.mouse.smooth_move(1700 / scale, 0 / scale)
```

Comment: always getting  autopy.screen.scale() is 1.0. Is this expected output?